# Using lists to make code less repetitive in R

Tags: r, list, vector, functional-programming

### Background:

Hi All,

I was hoping you can help me take my understanding & code to the next level. I'm trying to wrap my head around lists, their benefits, and using them to reduce redundant code. As much as I read about lists and the apply families online, I still cannot understand how to implement in my day-to-day work.

Here is a situation in which I imagine can be greatly simplified - this is the type of code that I often write, that I'm looking to replace with a more concise format.

### Example:

Let's pretend the entire `mtcars` data was for a single observation year - say 2018. Let's also pretend we had data going back annually to 2000. So there are now "18" mtcars data.frames with a year column that state the year and we take the 18 observations and bind by row into a single data.frame. This is an example of the type of data I am working with now. Observations seperated by year.

```
data <- mtcars %>%
group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(mpg))
         ))
```

### Data Manipulation I'd like to Simplify:

- Filtering: I want to filter all for a given year by different mpg ranks

  data %>%
  filter(gear == 4, date == '2005') %>%
  filter(rank %in% c(1:5))

  data %>%
  filter(gear == 4, date == '2005') %>%
  filter(rank %in% c(6:10))

  data %>%
  filter(gear == 4, date == '2005') %>%
  filter(rank %in% c(11:15))

What is the best way to simplify the redundant block of code above?

For example, I would like to make use of the `seq` function and do something along the lines of:

```
    data %>% 
filter(gear == 4, date == '2005') %>%
filter(rank %in% seq(1, 100, by = 5))
```

and store the outputs of each rank group into a list and then plot all of those lists in ggplot.

Comment: The question you are asking is very broad, i.e., how do I make my code, in general, less redundant? In the specific case of filtering, my tactic is to create "helper" data frames that can be joined to the main ones. For example, you might have a data frame with columns `year`, `min`, and `max`, join this to `mtcars` by "year", and then `filter(mtcars, year >= min & year <= max)`

Comment: You should instead be looking for functions that split rather than filter.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to work with lists and list columns in a tidy way can be kinda complicated. I recommend Jenny Bryan's `purrr` [tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/) a lot. Here, you're trying to avoid needing to do your `filter` lines a lot of times for different values of `year`, `gear` and `rank`. There's a few steps:

1. Figure out how to get all combinations of the values you want. We do this here with `purrr::cross_df`, which is a very convenient way to get combinations of variables.
2. Actually run the operation for each combination. Because our data is now nicely set up to have each row be a set of inputs, we can use `pmap` to store each filtered dataset as a list element. Depending on the plot we want, we can then use other tools like `unnest` to actually get the data into a format we want to plot.

I hope this can illustrate that in general if you realise you are doing something too many times, there are basically two steps; make a list or lists that you can iterate over, and use a `map` function to apply the operation you want to each list element.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars %>%
  bind_rows(
    mtcars %>% mutate(year = 2005),
    mtcars %>% mutate(year = 2006)
    ) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(mpg)))

combos <- cross_df(list(
  year = 2005:2006,
  gear = 3:5,
  start = seq(1, 100, by = 5)
  ))

combos %>%
  mutate(
    rank_range = map(start, ~ .x:(.x + 4)),
    filtered = pmap(
      .l = list(year, gear, rank_range),
      .f = ~ data %>%
        filter(gear == ..2, year == ..1) %>%
        filter(rank %in% ..3)
        )
    )
#> # A tibble: 120 x 5
#>     year  gear start rank_range filtered         
#>    <int> <int> <dbl> <list>     <list>           
#>  1  2005     3     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [0 x 13]>
#>  2  2006     3     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [0 x 13]>
#>  3  2005     4     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [4 x 13]>
#>  4  2006     4     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [4 x 13]>
#>  5  2005     5     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [2 x 13]>
#>  6  2006     5     1 <int [5]>  <tibble [2 x 13]>
#>  7  2005     3     6 <int [5]>  <tibble [2 x 13]>
#>  8  2006     3     6 <int [5]>  <tibble [2 x 13]>
#>  9  2005     4     6 <int [5]>  <tibble [6 x 13]>
#> 10  2006     4     6 <int [5]>  <tibble [6 x 13]>
#> # ... with 110 more rows
```

Created on 2018-05-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).